# Upload a document to a library with PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library, file-upload

I have a standalone 2013 SharePoint installed on a Win2012R2 which I am playing with.

When I click "Home" in the navigation this is my URL

```
http://winsrv01/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/
```

I created a new library name "SharePoint Doc Lib".

When I click on that library this is my URL:

```
http://winsrv01/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Sharepoint%20Doc%20Lib/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

Now I what to upload a file to this document library with powershell. Looking at [this how to](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=487) it seems pretty easy:

```
# Set the variables 
$WebURL = “http://portal.contoso.com/sites/stuff” 
$DocLibName = “Docs” 
$FilePath = “C:\Docs\stuff\Secret Sauce.docx” 


# Get a variable that points to the folder 
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL 
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName) 
$Files = $List.Files 

# Get just the name of the file from the whole path 
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1) 

# Load the file into a variable 
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

# Upload it to SharePoint 
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false) 
$web.Dispose()
```

1. But what will my URL be?
2. What is that `_layouts` all about?
3. What should the direct link to my library be?

Comment: Your web URL would be `http://winsrv01`. The `_layouts` bit is a result of the Minimal Download Strategy feature. Direct link to library would be `http://winsrv01/Sharepoint%20Doc%20Lib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the browser is because of a new feature in SharePoint 2013 Called Minimal Download Strategy. That's why you are seeing `_Layouts/15/start.aspx#/Sharepoint%20Doc%20Lib/Forms/AllItems.aspx`:

[Read this](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds)

> Minimal Download Strategy is a new feature in SharePoint 2013 that
>   improves client rendering performance and fluidity when navigating
>   from page to page by download only the changes between two compatible
>   pages. Fewer bytes will be downloaded and the page will appear more
>   quickly.

**_Layouts:** The _layouts directory hosts application pages, which contain general administration and settings for SharePoint Products and Technologies. Pages in the _layouts folder operate much like any ASPX page, for example, allowing inline code. However, they cannot contain Web Part zones.
The _layouts folder refers to the following file system location:

```
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\**12or 14 or 15 or 16**\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb815343(v=office.12).aspx

Your direct URL to the Library is: `http://winsrv01/Sharepoint%20Doc%20Lib`. But if MDS enabled(which is by default) it will be converted to MDS.